# VSCode keeps dependency with an older virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I am trying to create a new virtual environment for my python project. I run the following command:

```bash
python -m venv venv
```

and then I activate the virtual environment using

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

When I install the libraries and run the script it keeps going to an older virtual environment that I used in a legacy project. Although I don't need it at all.

I couldn't understand where's the problem within vscode because it keeps using the same virtual environment even that I tried creating new ones for test purposes.

Comment: "When I install the libraries and run the script" install how, and run how? (Are you using plugins? Are you manually running pyton -m pip inside a venv-activated terminal? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After your creating the virtual environment, you have to choose the python interpreter in VsCode.

Using shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the virtual environment and VsCode will activate it automatically.

Reading [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command) for more details.

Comment: I always do that. Apparently I had to move the folder that was always showing up as a virtual environment from the older project to another place and it worked fine. I don't know if it is a vs code production bug or I just have some interpreter settings going wrong.

Comment: If your way solves your problem, I think you can consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.